# Neo4j Desktop - Where are Remote Graphs stored?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I'm new to Neo4j and am learning the Desktop application. I see that I can Add a Database (I can either Create a Local Graph or Connect to a Remote Graph). Creating a local graph obviously means creating a database on my computer, one with it's own bolt://... URL ID of some sort. If instead I Add a Remote Graph, does this imply that I can connect to another local graph stored on my laptop for example if I know its bolt id? I presume I can't but I want to make sure.

Next, if Remote implies stored in the cloud or served somehow, short of setting up a Neo4j instance on AWS or via another 3rd party does Neo4j come with its own easy way to setup a "remote" instance and where would this live? Does Neo have it's own cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Remote Graph implies that there's a running Neo4j instance out there "somewhere" that we can connect to via the bolt URL, similar to how we would connect from a client application using a Neo4j driver (after all, Neo4j Desktop and Neo4j Browser are both client applications and connect via Neo4j drivers).

That might be a server instance somewhere set up by your company, or an instance running from your own laptop (not launched from Desktop), or maybe a [Neo4j Aura](https://neo4j.com/aura/) instance you've set up yourself, or something on AWS or another cloud.

You can't administer remote instances, as bolt connections do not allow for starting/stopping Neo4j or other operations that require command-line access (though 4.0 security administration via the system db is supported).

For the most part though Desktop is agnostic of where or how the remote instance is set up, it just requires a bolt URL that can be used to connect to the instance or cluster.